# HTTPS Spoofing in order to support legacy application

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, spoofing

I have a legacy application that has a hardcoded url (I don't have access to the source) in which it tries to download a file. The url takes the form:

https://pre.hostname.org/index.json

but the organization that hosts that site has dropped that hostname and is using a new hostname, so that the url should be of the form:

https://hostname2.org/pre/index.json

I don't own the application source code or either website, but it occurred to me that I might be able to do some spoofing if I set up a redirect on my local webserver and point the old hostname to my webserver using the C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

On my webserver in a lighttpd conf file:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "https" {
     $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
       url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)$" => "https://hostname2.org/pre$0" )
    }
}
```

On the client machine with the legacy application in the hosts file:

```
0.0.0.0 hostname.org
```

(0.0.0.0 represents the hostname of my webserver with the redirect instructions)

With this setup I can, on the client machine, access the old url in a web browser, and the redirect happens. However, it does not work from the legacy application, and I think it's due to the SSL certification hostname not matching.

If I use Edge browser, for example, I have to workaround the warning:

```
The hostname in the website's security certificate differs from the website you are trying to visit.

Error Code:
DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID
```

I have administrator access on the client machine, the webserver, etc. I obviously trust my webserver even though it doesn't match the cert...

I totally accept that this is as it should be -- that this is part of the protection that https and SSL certificates provide -- what I'm asking is, is there a way to cause my legacy application to ignore this situation? A way to circumvent https protection for this particular hostname / certificate system-wide, so that it will take effect for whatever API the legacy app is using to download the file through https?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to cause my legacy application to ignore this situation?

Since you only have the binary of the application you might try to replace the hard-coded domain name in the application with a domain you control, i.e. binary patching. Note that would not work if the application is signed since it would break the signature.

You could also try to create your own CA, import it as trusted into your system and use this CA to create your own certificate for the domain in question. If the application just does the simple certificate verification without any pinning of certificate or CA and with using the systems trust store, then it should accept the certificate you've created yourself because it trusts your CA and should thus accept the redirect.